# What kind of input can I use for pandas?

Tags: pandas, input

Which type of objects can I use to create a Pandas series? Reading the documentation apparently any array-like object can be used as input. I would have thought that a numpy ndarray object is array-like, but apparently it isn't, as the code below shows.

```
pd.Series([[2,3],[5,6]]) #ok

ar = np.array([[2,3],[5,6]])
pd.Series(ar) #throws exception
```

Comment: it has to be a 1-dimensional array

Comment: With your first line, `pd.Series()`  is coercing each sub-list to type `object` and returning a series of those -- it's not a 2-dimensional `Series`.